# How to draw a single line in a certain area, and it continues from where it stopped

Tags: flutter, dart, button, drawing, line

I just figured out how to draw a line with arrow buttons. However, it doesn't draw the line correctly. Therefore, I was wondering if someone can help me out with drawing just one line in a drawing area(Ideally in a scrollable box) and each time when releasing the button and tapping again, it should continue from where it stopped please?

This is what it looks like rn:

[Drawing lines with arrow buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9uus.png)

Here's part of my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Transform.rotate(
    angle: radians(0),
    child: Stack(
        alignment:
            Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topCenter, Alignment.center, 0.50),
        children: [
          ImageInput(_selectImage),
          _buildButton(0, color: Colors.red, icon: Icons.east),
          _buildButton(45, color: Colors.green, icon: Icons.south_east),
          _buildButton(90, color: Colors.orange, icon: Icons.south),
          _buildButton(135, color: Colors.blue, icon: Icons.south_west),
          _buildButton(180, color: Colors.black, icon: Icons.west),
          _buildButton(225, color: Colors.indigo, icon: Icons.north_west),
          _buildButton(270, color: Colors.pink, icon: Icons.north),
          _buildButton(315, color: Colors.yellow, icon: Icons.north_east),
        ]));
}



_buildButton(double angle, {Color color, IconData icon}) {
final double rad = radians(angle);
return Transform(
  transform: Matrix4.identity()
    ..translate(
      100 * cos(rad),
      100 * sin(rad),
    ),
  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
      child: Container(),
    ),
    CustomPaint(
      foregroundPainter: LinePainter(_offset),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(icon),
        backgroundColor: color,
        onPressed: () {
          HoldDetector(
            onHold: _incrementCounter(angle),
            holdTimeout: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            enableHapticFeedback: true,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: _incrementCounter(angle),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ]),
 );
}

_incrementCounter(double angle) {
 _cnt += 10;
 switch (angle.round()) {
   case 0:
     setState(() {
       _offset = Offset(_cnt, 0);
     });
     break;

   case 45:
     setState(() {
       _offset = Offset(_cnt, _cnt);
     });
     break;

   case 90:
     setState(() {
       _offset = Offset(0, _cnt);
     });
     break;

   case 135:
     setState(() {
       _offset = Offset(-_cnt, _cnt);
     });
     break;

   case 180:
     setState(() {
       _offset = Offset(-_cnt, 0);
     });
     break;

   case 225:
     setState(() {
       _offset = Offset(-_cnt, -_cnt);
     });
     break;

   case 270:
     setState(() {
       _offset = Offset(0, -_cnt);
     });
     break;

   case 315:
     setState(() {
       _offset = Offset(_cnt, -_cnt);
     });
     break;
   }
  }
 }

class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
 Paint _paint;
 Offset _offset;

 LinePainter(Offset offset) {
  _offset = offset;
  _paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..strokeWidth = 8.0;
 }

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, 0), _offset, _paint);
}

@override
bool shouldRepaint(LinePainter oldDelegate) {
  return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide a sample code.

Comment: Hi,
I have attached the sample code.
Thank you!